# How can I get a plot window in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am able to run the plot command successfully but not able to view the graph/chart window in RStudio. I can save it using "dev.off" command in my hard disk and then open it. I have checked all the options in the GUI but did not find it. I wonder if there is any package to be installed. Please suggest.

Comment: Menu “View” > “Show Plots”.

Comment: When I'm in R Console, I don't see the "Show Plots" option under View menu. I can see only two options i.e Toolbar & Statusbar.  I am not able to add the snapshot here orelse would have added it.

Comment: R Console ≠ RStudio! Which is it?!

Comment: I apologise, i was facing the above issue with R Console in RGui. Now i installed R Studio and by default i can view all the options. The problem is i didn't/don't know the difference b/w R Console & R Studio. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking if the Plots tab is enabled in the global options panel?

Click "Tools" > "Global Options" and then go to "Pane Layout." The "Plots" tab should be present and enabled in one of your panes as shown below:

[image: RStudio]

Answer (score 0):

I often have this problem. I do not know why, but quitting and restarting R usually solves it for me.